# Best way to validate and read files from a date wise folder in Java

Tags: java, file, date

I have to validate and read .txt files from a date wise folder. Need suggestions on best possible ways to achieve this

I will have a property file which will have following information

```
value active channel
5092   Y      11
5092   Y      12
5092   Y      13
5093   N      10
5093   N      11
```

from this property file first i need get active value(i.e. 5092) and their channel information i.e 11,12,13

based on the above information need to iterate files from a date wise folder.

```
Input(folder)
  10JUN2017
    HW_5092_ABC_11.txt
    HW_5092_ABC_12.txt
    HW_5092_ABC_13.txt
  11JUN2017
    HW_5092_ABC_11.txt
    HW_5092_ABC_12.txt
```

Based on the property file information (i.e. 5092 is active file and it has channel 11,12,13) look for the current date folder i.e. 11JUN2017 then look for files of 5092. If 11JUN2017 has files related to 5092 (i.e. all 3 files 11,12 and 13) then need to read files from 11JUN2017 folder and process the files. Else need to go back to previous date then look for the files.
In the above example, 11JUN2017 does not have all the files so, i need to go back to previous date i.e. 10JUN2017 and look for the files if found then process it. If 10JUN2017 also does not have all files then go back to previous date (max no of days to traverse back is 43 days).

### Update

There is some change in my requirement. There will not be date wise folder instead file name itself contains date in YYYYMMdd format and all files will be in single folder, for example, filename will be like as follows BIG_ABCHINE_MATERIAL_2092_11_20170614-150136-243.txt.

So below is what I am trying

```
public void fileLoadingProcess() {

             //Reading text file which contains all the information
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\OrgDetails.txt"));

            in.readLine();
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

                values = str.split("\t");

                //Adding config property values to Map
                if (values[5].equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    System.out.println("Active sales org " + values[0]);

                    if (distChannelMap.containsKey(values[0])) {
                        list = distChannelMap.get(values[0]);
                        list.add(Integer.parseInt(values[6]));
                    } else {
                        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        list.add(Integer.parseInt(values[6]));
                        distChannelMap.put(values[0], list);

                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Inactive Sales org " + values[0]);
                }

            }
            Set set = distChannelMap.entrySet();
            Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                System.out.println("Key -->  " + mentry.getKey() + " Value(s)  -->" + mentry.getValue());
                //Calling this method to check file needs to be processed based on active and inactive states
                isFileNeedsToBeProcessed(mentry.getKey().toString(), (ArrayList<Integer>) mentry.getValue());
            }

            //Check whether this file is exists or not
//            

    }

public void isFileNeedsToBeProcessed(String salesOrg, ArrayList<Integer> distChannel) {


        System.out.println("Previous Day " + new TxtToXMLCommon().previousDate(1));
        //String previousDate = new TxtToXMLCommon().getCurrentDate();
        for (int i = 0; i < distChannel.size(); i++) {
            int x =1;
             previousDate = new TxtToXMLCommon().previousDate(x);

            System.out.println("Distribution channel " + distChannel.get(i));

            File folder = new File(Constants.INPUT_FOLDER);

            File[] files = folder.listFiles();
            if (files.length == 0) {
                _logger.info("***No files present to process***");
                return;
            } else {

                for (int k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
                    if (files[k].getName().contains("MATERIAL")) {

                        if (salesOrg.equalsIgnoreCase(files[k].getName().substring(21, 25))
                                && (distChannel.get(i) == Integer.parseInt(files[k].getName().substring(26, 28)))&& 
                                previousDate.equalsIgnoreCase(files[k].getName().substring(29, 37))) {

                            System.out.println("File present to process " + files[k].getName());
                            break;


//                            if () {
//                                //processingFilesMap.put("MATERIAL", files[k].getName());
//                                System.out.println("File present to process " + files[k].getName());
//                            }else{
//                                
//                            }

                        }else{
                            //previousDate = new TxtToXMLCommon().previousDate(x+1);

                        }
                        //previousDate = new TxtToXMLCommon().previousDate(2);

                    }//end of if(MATERIAL)
                }// end of files length 


            }

        }

    }
```

But I am little bit stuck here while finding for the file in a folder(single source folder). Say, as you see, I have put the property file information in the distChannelMap and then for each value I am iterating source folder and trying to find the file which contains org value values[0] and key values[6] which I have stored in arraylist. because for one value 5092 there are 3 channel.

Now if I do not find file matching org value (5092), channel (11) and date (20170615), I need to iterate the folder again with date-1 means value 5092, channel 11 and date 20170614 like this till 43 days. once i found the file I am thinking to put it into map so that I have all files which are ready to process. But I am little bit stuck in going to previous date when i do not the file for particular channel. once this channel is find, I need to do the same process for other channels like 12 and 13 for the org 5092.

Comment: Is there always just one active value (like 5092 in the example)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. No,  the property file contains many active values, may be few values are inactive  and this property file contains many values. so is it good idea to read current date folder then look for the file name, from this file name take the value(2092) then check the property file  whether it is active or not, if it is not active then look for the next file.  because current date folder might not have all values files.

Comment: The update gives me the impression this question is rather too broad. It looks like you're wanting quite a bit of work from volunteers. Since this question has not seen any activity since June (and there is a good reply that is unresponded to) I think it is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

I think it’s simplest to take one channel at a time.

Construct the file name from active value and channel number, for example

```
String.format("HW_%d_ABC_%d.txt", activeValue, channel)
```

Use `LocalDate` for the folder names.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMuuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String folderName = date.format(dateFormatter).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT);
```

Think twice about the time zone to use. `ZoneId.systemDefault()` will give you the JVM’s current setting, it may not be what you need. I am typing this on June 10th and understand that in your time zone it’s already June 11th. Would be a pity to miss today’s files because of incorrect time zone.

In a loop, look for the file in the folder. If found, exit the loop. If not found, do

```
    date = date.minusDays(1);
    folderName = date.format(dateFormatter).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT);
```

This will give you the folder name of the previous day’s folder. Then look there.

This will work across the beginning of the month and the beginning of the year. For the limit of looking 43 days back, either use a counter or set

```
    LocalDate limit = date.minusDays(43);
```

and then give up when `date.isBefore(limit)`.

**Edit** If you want to start from the folders and files, look into `Files.newDirectoryStream(Path, String)`. You may use it first to find the folders of this month and the previous two months (that should cover 43 days and more), maybe filter and sort them. Next for each folder you can use the same method to determine which files are present. You will have a challenge keeping track of which files are present in more than one folder and which one is the newest, it can be solved. I am not immediately convinced about the advantage of this approach, but I trust you to make a good decision for yourself.